# How to copy ajax success result to clipbaord

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clipboard

i have a ajax method which gets the data from a controller and display in the Jquery Dialog Box. My goal is to have a button within the dialog box that will allow the data with a click instead of the user highlighting the data using the mouse and copying.

Ajax

```
    function GrabLink(surveyName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Survey/sendLink",
        data: { test: surveyName },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            $('#my-dialog').html(data);
            $("#my-dialog").dialog("open");

            //alert(data);
            //$("#my-dialog").show(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Jquery Dialog

```
    $('#my-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Copy': function ()
        {
            //window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
           // $(this).dialog('close');

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/).

Comment: Is my solution answer resolve your issue?

Comment: yes it did marked it as a valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `execCommand` for copy on clipboard with `javascript`. Create an input temporally, put data inside and remove it:

```
function clipboard(){
    var mydata = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(mydata);
    mydata.setAttribute("id", "mydata_id");
    document.getElementById("mydata_id").value=Yourdata-success-response;  
    mydata.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(mydata);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code which copies data without selection of text/data

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CopyToClipboard () {
            var input = document.getElementById ("toClipboard");
            var textToClipboard = input.value;
            
            var success = true;
            if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
                window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", textToClipboard);
            }
            else {
                    // create a temporary element for the execCommand method
                var forExecElement = CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard);

                        /* Select the contents of the element 
                            (the execCommand for 'copy' method works on the selection) */
                SelectContent (forExecElement);

                var supported = true;

                    // UniversalXPConnect privilege is required for clipboard access in Firefox
                try {
                    if (window.netscape && netscape.security) {
                        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege ("UniversalXPConnect");
                    }

                        // Copy the selected content to the clipboard
                        // Works in Firefox and in Safari before version 5
                    success = document.execCommand ("copy", false, null);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    success = false;
                }
                
                    // remove the temporary element
                document.body.removeChild (forExecElement);
            }

            if (success) {
                alert ("The text is on the clipboard, try to paste it!");
            }
            else {
                alert ("Your browser doesn't allow clipboard access!");
            }
        }

        function CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard) {
            var forExecElement = document.createElement ("div");
                // place outside the visible area
            forExecElement.style.position = "absolute";
            forExecElement.style.left = "-10000px";
            forExecElement.style.top = "-10000px";
                // write the necessary text into the element and append to the document
            forExecElement.textContent = textToClipboard;
            document.body.appendChild (forExecElement);
                // the contentEditable mode is necessary for the  execCommand method in Firefox
            forExecElement.contentEditable = true;

            return forExecElement;
        }

        function SelectContent (element) {
                // first create a range
            var rangeToSelect = document.createRange ();
            rangeToSelect.selectNodeContents (element);

                // select the contents
            var selection = window.getSelection ();
            selection.removeAllRanges ();
            selection.addRange (rangeToSelect);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="toClipboard" value="text to clipboard"/>
    <button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy text to clipboard</button>
</body
```